# C++ merging duplicated search results from arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class, merge

Okay so I have an array like this:

```
class name {
  public:
    string first;
    int last;

  name(string a, int b){
    first = a;
    last = b;
  }
};

name arr[] { { "John", 1 }, { "Jane", 2 }, { "Dick", 3 }, { "John", 1 }, { "Jane", 2 } };
```

For now I am only able to print them all out like this:

```
int main() {

    int icount = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(name);

    for (int i = 0; i < icount; i++){
        cout << arr[i].first << " " << arr[i].last << endl;
    }

}

Output will be like this:
John 1
Jane 2
Dick 3
John 1
Jane 2
```

However I need merge any similar results, meaning if the name is the same I need to add up the numbers behind them. The desired output should be like this:

```
John 2
Jane 4
Dick 3
```

Is there any function I can use to merge them or how should I go about doing it?

Comment: Look up the standard algorithms `unique()` or `unique_copy()`.   Depending on your needs, you may need to sort your container first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++ you can use Map to finish your job.

Here is the complete program you need.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<string, int> mer;

class name
{
public:
    string first;
    int last;

    name (string a, int b)
    {
        first = a;
        last = b;
    }
};

name arr[] { { "John", 1 }, { "Jane", 2 }, { "Dick", 3 }, { "John", 1 }, { "Jane", 2 } };

void merge()
{
    int icount = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < icount; i++)
    {
         if (mer.count(arr[i].first) > 0)
         {
             mer[arr[i].first]++;
         }
         else
         {
             mer[arr[i].first] = 1;
         }
    }
}

 int main()
 {
    int icount = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(name);
    merge();
    map<string,int>::iterator it;
    for(it = mer.begin(); it != mer.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will print the result of what you expected. Of course it will print in reverse order. You can use reverse iterator to get the desired result.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.. I get this warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|.

Comment: @Pokee so your example shouldn't compile either. Add `-std=c++11` to your compilation command. The way you initialize your array requires C++11

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;


class name {
public:
    string first;
    int last;

    name(string a, int b);
};

name::name(string a, int b) : first(a), last(b)
{

}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string names[] =
    {
        "John", "Jane", "Dick", "John", "Jane"  
    };

    int values[] =
    {
        1, 2, 3, 1, 2  
    };

    vector<name> people;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(names) / sizeof(*names); ++i)
    {
        people.push_back(name(names[i], values[i]));
    }

    map<string, int> unique_people;
    for (vector<name>::const_iterator it = people.begin(), 
         end = people.end(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        if (unique_people.count(it->first) != 0)
        {
            unique_people[it->first] += it->last;
        }
        else
        {
            unique_people.insert(pair<string, int>(it->first, it->last));
        }
    }

    for (map<string, int>::const_reverse_iterator it = unique_people.rbegin(),
         end = unique_people.rend(); it != end; ++it)
    {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```